# LaTeX: how to include an index in the middle of a book

Tags: indexing

I need to include an index in the middle of a book, because I am writing a multi-volume work by splitting a large pdf into 5 volumes, and the index should appear at the end of the first volume.

If I do `\printidex` in the place where I want the index, then only items indexed up to that point appear.  The remaining `\indexentry` are just written by LaTeX to stdout, and thus never get into the index.

Is there a simple solution to this?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
aaa\index{aaa}
\printindex
\clearpage % with this in, the index omits bbb; otherwise it's ok :(
bbb\index{bbb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "If I do \printidex in the place where I want the index, then only items indexed up to that point appear. " I see no reason why that should happen if you are using standard definitions `\printindex` is just `\newcommand\printindex{\@input@{\jobname.ind}}` it inputs the makeindex built file if it's there but does nothing to change the index collection.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - yes, that's how I see it.  I am using latexmk and possibly it's doing something tricky.  I'll try again with manual pdflatex and makeidx commands.

Comment: PS: when `\printindex` is in the middle of the document, I see multiple items like this `\indexentry{Bradfield|hyperpage}{1023}` on stdout after `\printindex`.  With the normal index at the end, these don't appear.

Comment: That's the expected behaviour if you `\write` to a filestream that's been closed, but the standard `\printindex` does not close the `.idx` file stream so I guess you are using a non standard definition, perhaps one of the multi-index packages that has to close and re-open the collection to do per-chapter indices or whatever. But as you have shown no code, only you can answer.

Comment: make a small 5-line complete example that has `\index{aaa}\printindex\index{bbb}` and shows the problem

Comment: I am using two indices, but that's the only slightly unusual thing I am doing.  Sorry about the lack of code, but it's an extremely complex and large book built from multiple .tex files.   If I can't figure it out, I'll post a MWE later.

Comment: well I would imagine you have redefined `\printindex` to close the stream.  But just use `\InputIfFileExists{whatever.ind}` instead, that's more or less bound to work

Comment: Thanks again - MWE now added.  Your `\InputIfFileExists{whatever.ind}` seems to work in my MWE, though it eats a bit of following text.  I'll try it in my big book.

Comment: With `\InputIfFileExists{whatever.ind}{}{}` in my big book, everything seems ok.  But I'm still not sure why `\clearpage` makes a difference in my MWE.

Comment: `\usepackage{imakeidx}` I suspected that (good we can blame @egreg)